# How do you teleport a player relatively but without finishing at 0.5 on each axis?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Basically I have a command block on repeat without need of redstone and the command is:

```
execute if entity @p[dy=1] run tp @p ~7 80 ~-20
```

The purpose of it is to attempt seamless teleport which has worked... well sort of. When i walk over it, it teleports me to the correct coordinates but always finishing at 0.5. What I mean is this, if my x coordinate is 123.2152 then if i teleport relatively to -2 blocks then it ends up at 121.5 not 121.2152.

How do I get it to end up at not 0.5?

Answer (score 1):

You just have to add `.0` to turn it into an exact number:

```
/tp @s 100.0 100.0 100.0
```

teleports you exactly to 100.0 100.0 100.0 without centering you in the block.

Btw, this is not a behaviour of the relative teleport, so it wouldn't change anything in your example command. I assume your example command is in a command block, in that case it teleports you relative to the command block bottom center, so you would have to subtract 0.5 from the x and z coordinate to end up on a block corner.

Comment: I'm not trying to end up at the corner of a block and yes it is in a command block. I've tried using @s and it still teleports to half block precision.

Comment: As I said, it's not `@s` that does it, that just selects yourself. It's `.0`.